# Mailcore 2 iOS How to retrieve Reply email address

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailcore2

Mailcore 2 integration:

I am working on "Reply", "Reply All" , "Forward" and Move To features. When I started up with "Reply", I could able to get the Reply mail body full message from `MCOMessageView class` -> `content = [(MCOIMAPMessage *) _message htmlRenderingWithFolder:_folder delegate:self];` and displayed in reply compose view.
Now, I need pre-populate "Reply" (Recipient To) email in the compose view. When I tried "_message.header.replyTo", it is giving me like "mailcore::Address:0x17df0c70 getsy sandriya getsypri8796@gmail.com"

But I need to retrieve the mail address(es) alone from this "_message.header.replyTo", it is giving me like "mailcore::Address:0x17df0c70 getsy sandriya getsypri8796@gmail.com"

How to retrieve Reply email address from "mailcore:.........", please advise.

Comment: Use [[_message.header.replyTo lastObject] mailbox]

Comment: Thanks. It is giving me the email address separately. Thank you. What If i need to get all the email addresses for "Reply All" ?

Comment: I got the email addresses from _message.header.to, _message.header.cc, _message.header.bcc

Answer (score 0):

The definitive answer for me is like the following, i made a quick Swift v2.3 example and it run like the following :

```
let imapsession = MCOIMAPSession()
    imapsession.hostname = "YOUR SERVER"
    imapsession.port = 993
    imapsession.username = "EMAIL"
    imapsession.password = "PASS"
    imapsession.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.TLS

    let requestKind : MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.Headers

    let folder : String = "INBOX"
    let uids : MCOIndexSet = MCOIndexSet(range: MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX))

    let fetchOperation : MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation = imapsession.fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder(folder, requestKind: requestKind, uids: uids)

    fetchOperation.start { (err, msg, vanished) -> Void in
        print("error from server \(err)")
        print("fetched \(msg?[0]) messages")
        let msgs = msg
        if msgs?.count > 0 {
            for m in msgs! {
                let MSG: MCOIMAPMessage = m as! MCOIMAPMessage
                let op = imapsession.fetchMessageByUIDOperationWithFolder(folder, uid: MSG.uid)
                op.start { (err, data) -> Void in
                    let msgParser = MCOMessageParser(data: data)
                    let html: String = msgParser.plainTextBodyRendering()
                    print("*********************")
                    print("Mail body\(html)")
                    print("mail sender:\(MSG.header.sender)")
                    print("mail recipient:\(MSG.header.to)")
                    print("mail subject:\(MSG.header.subject)")
                    print("*********************")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the example above i went a bit far and i gather the mail content as text. you can do it in HTML also.

Hope this answer will help you and help other people who fall in the same issue !